# Segmentation Fault and isalpha

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, isalpha

I want to clear up my understanding of Segmentation faults while using command-line arguments and `isalpha()` but this particular situation confused me more.
So I declared `argv[1]` a `char *` as a way around it as advised by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392712/isalpha-check-on-argument-results-in-segmentation-fault) SO answer.

However, `Segmentation Fault` still occurs if I used less than 2 command line arguments, and `isalpha()` is ignored in the if 3rd condition

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //atoi is here

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    char *input = argv[1];
    // Error handling
    if ((argc > 2) || (argc < 1) || (isalpha(input[1])))
    {
        printf("Unwanted input\n");
        return 1;
    }
   
    return 0;

}
```

Why do I get [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20undefined%20behavior,which%20the%20computer%20code%20adheres.&text=In%20the%20C%20community%2C%20undefined,std.) when not using a command-line argument, and why then does `isalpha()` get ignored rather than giving me a seg fault?

Thanks for taking the time to read this post

Comment: You get a segfault when you supply no arguments because in that case, argc is 1; argv[1] is NULL, and NULL[1] is undefined behaviour, usually a segfault (so isalpha is never called, because its argument could not be computed).

Comment: `char *input = argv[1];` should be after you check that `argc > 1`, not before. As an aside, I don't recommend typedefing away `char *`. Just be explicit instead of hiding the pointer.

Comment: Where does `string` come from?

Comment: @alk Probably from an unstated `#include <cs50.h>`, in which case it's a `typedef` for `char*`

Comment: @rici. Thanks for your answer! `isalpha()` still doesn't do anything at all even after solving the segfault. I've even tried putting it in a separate `if else` statement. 

`else if (isalpha(input[1])) { printf("Not accepting alphabet\n"); }`

Comment: @ggorlen If I try put `char *input = argv[1]` I get a `error: expected expression
    else if (isalpha(input[1]))` when I put the `isalpha()` lower or I get `undeclared identifier 'input'`.

Comment: @alk Sorry, yeah. It's from the cs50 library. Read `string` as `char*`

Comment: Yes, you obviously can't just move it in one go and expect to be finished with the refactor or you'll get errors because `input` won't have been declared. You need to rearrange the logic in a couple steps, but however you decide to do it, the point is that you're indexing out of bounds before you've bothered checking the length and that is going to cause a segfault. Write logic that always guarantees the index will be in bounds before doing it.

Comment: Another bug: it should be `isalpha((unsigned char)input[1])` in case `char` is signed on your system.  Some libraries will let you get away without it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute the program with no args, `argc` is `1` (cause the program name itself counts as an arg), and `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

```c
(argc > 2) || (argc < 1)   // Considers argc == 1 and argc == 2 acceptable
```

should be

```c
(argc > 2) || (argc < 2)    // Only considers argc == 2 acceptable
```

or just

```c
argc != 2
```